# Loop for a taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have some trouble with a loop. I need to display some div every 6 iterations

```
<div class="category_block">    
<?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
    <div class="category_item">
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
        <span><?php echo $cat->category_count; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create some variable and can check that variable's value. If that's 6, 12, or 18 etc ... then you can put your  etc ... have a code example below:

```
<div class="category_block">    
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) :
$counter++;
?>

    <div class="category_item">
     <?php if($counter % 6 == 0) {>
     <div class="custom-div"></div> 
    <?php } ?>
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
        <span><?php echo $cat->category_count; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Hope, that solves your issue.

Comment: thx for your answer, but this code display div before every iteration

Comment: That's code is for example purposes so that you can use as you want. Well, let me know where you want your div to put so that I can give you exact code that will work for you.

Comment: I think it should look like: <category_item1>,<category_item2>,<category_item3>,<category_item4>,<category_item5>,<category_item6>,<custom div>,<category_item7>.....

Comment: I have changed mine code, you can use that code now, it will work fine now. Let me know if you have further issue or your problem solves.

Comment: It still put div in every iteration

Comment: I have changed the code, a little update and it will work for you now, sorry there was a mistake in mine code I really sorry for that

Comment: Just copy whole of mine code and paste where you want to, it will work fine for you.